# How to use MBProgressHUD with MKNetworkKit?

Tags: mbprogresshud, mknetworkkit

Im using MKNetworkKit with protocols and delegates to send service calls and get json response. Now I want to implement MBProgressHUD to show a busy indicator while the data is being fetched and loaded on the UITable View.

I send the request in viewDidLoad;

```
            - (void)viewDidLoad
            {
                [super viewDidLoad];
                // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

                [[DataEngine sharedEngine]setFetchUserDataDelegate:self];
                [[DataEngine sharedEngine]fetchUserData:@"1"]; 
             }
```

Where Data Engine is my singleton class where I declared the fetchUserData Method.

I have included the required files i-e; MBProgressHUD.h & MBProgressHUD.m in my project.

Now which code I should write to start and stop the busy indicator and where should I write that code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Download project files from Here: https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD
2) Include MBProgressHUD.h & MBProgressHUD.m files into your project directory.
3) Create an instance variable like: MBProgressHUD *progressHUD in your .h file.
4) In .m file, write following code;

```
progressHUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc]initWithView:self.view];
[progressHUD show:YES];
[self.view addSubView:progressHUD];
```

5) To stop the progress indicator write;

```
[progressHUD hide:YES];
```